# Статические и нестатические переменные и методы

Tags: java

Как я знаю, к статическим переменным и методом мы обращаемся через класс, а к нестатическим - через объект.

Есть такой код

```
public class Training {

    static int a = 3;
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Training.a++;    // но можно и так: a++;
        Training.fu();   // но можно и так: fu();
    }

    static void fu() {
        System.out.println("hello");
    }
}
```

Мне удобно писать статические переменные и методы через имя класса (`Training.a`), так я сразу понимаю что данная переменная или метод статичны.
Вопрос в том, каким образом пишут большинство программистов и стоит ли мне так писать или лучше отвыкнуть от этого?

Comment: Дольше пост оформлять на SO, чем разобраться в этом вопросе.

Comment: По мне так норм вопрос. +1

Comment: Некоторым удобнее обращаться использовать специальное соглашение об именованиях, делающее имена статических полей, нестатических полей и локальных переменных и аргументов непересекающимися. Например префикс `s_a`.

Comment: отличный вопрос, кто минусует там?

Answer (score 3):

> Мне удобно писать статические переменные и методы через имя класса (Training.a), так я сразу понимаю что данная переменная или метод статичны. Вопрос в том, каким образом пишут большинство программистов и стоит ли мне так писать или лучше отвыкнуть от этого?

Вопрос конечно же касается [coding conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coding_conventions). Конкретно в Java code convention (раздел 10.2) [оба подхода одобрены](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-programmingpractices.html):

```
classMethod();             //OK
AClass.classMethod();      //OK
anObject.classMethod();    //AVOID!
```

Я лично таки придерживаюсь практики указания названия класса, то есть `Training.fu()`